Cannot install a working driver on Ubuntu 24.04 for my GeForce GT 240 (Tried a lot of different ways)
I installed version 24.04 on a computer that has a GeForce GT 240 card. I am having a crazy amount of trouble getting it to work. After many attempts, by restoring the nouveau graphics driver, I finally managed to see the interface at 1920x1080, but now after a few seconds or minutes, the system freezes. Previously, I had tried to install the drivers with the procedure:
apt update
apt upgrade

add-apt-repository ppa:graphics-drivers/ppa
apt update

dpkg -l | grep nvidia
apt-get purge nvidia-*
apt-get autoremove

ubuntu-drivers devices
apt install nvidia-drivers-550
nvidia-xconfig
update-initramfs -u

reboot

Then I tried to install directly from a command-line only reboot:
sh ./NVIDIA-Linux-x86_64-270.41.06.run

This is a driver that supports the GT 240. Worse than ever: I only had 640x480 at reboot. I have tried everything. I can't figure out what is wrong. NOTE: I am not an expert in Ubuntu and the operating system commands. I use it to have a Python environment for development.
Last try, I rebooted in command line mode and followed this procedure:
sudo apt delete --purge nvidia*
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:kelebek333/nvidia-legacy
sudo apt update
sudo apt install nvidia-340-updates nvidia-340-updates-dev xorg-modulepath-fix
sudo reboot

Now, when the system starts, I see the initial Ubuntu screen, the one with the logo, at a resolution of 640x480, then a black screen with a cursor (underscore) in the top left corner, still at the same resolution, and a beep every two or three seconds from the speaker. The graphical interface no longer appears as it did before
I have no idea how to fix this.
UPDATE
I changed that old GeForce 240 with a newer GeForce 750, but I still have problems to see the GUI. I suspect that there is some problem in some config file but I am not so expert to troubleshoot this problem.

You are using the newest version of Ubuntu released only a few months ago with an extremely old graphics card released in November 17th, 2009 It is quite likely it is not going to work with this setup. Try to boot from a live media for say 20.04 and see how the graphics look.

On really old systems, nouveau should work. Nouveau just does not support all the features of the very new nVidia cards/chips. Did you also uninstall the .run using its uninstall as any duplicate driver creates issues.

I changed the graphic card and substituted the GeForce 240 with a GeForce 750 but I still have problems to see the Ubuntu GUI.

never use *  with apt. It is not a wildcard for the package but a bash expansion

we nowadays use 1 method for installing drivers: ubuntu-drivers on command line Please use that.

I tried also that, with no success. It looks like there is no way to have GeForce 750 working on the latest version of Ubuntu. Sigh

I tried that too, with no success.
